# Can someone help me with this syntax error print name.find('s')?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python 3.5.1. I have a variable called `name` and the value assigned is sarah. I get a syntax error when I type `print name.find('s')`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `print()` is a function and requires parentheses:
`print(name.find('s'))`